# ngx-color-picker installation getting an error

Tags: angular

I'm trying to install ngx-color-picker in my Angular application following these instructions:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-color-picker/v/16.0.0

Installing it using the command below works successfully:

`npm install ngx-color-picker --save`

I can run `ng serve` and no error occurs.

But when I import it like below:

```
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [
    ...
    ColorPickerModule
  ]
})
```

I get this error when executing `ng serve`:

```
Error: node_modules/ngx-color-picker/lib/color-picker.directive.d.ts:108:103 - error TS2344: Type '{ colorPicker: { alias: "colorPicker"; required: false; }; cpWidth: { alias: "cpWidth"; required: false; }; cpHeight: { alias: "cpHeight"; required: false; }; cpToggle: { alias: "cpToggle"; required: false; }; ... 33 more ...; cpExtraTemplate: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
  Property '"colorPicker"' is incompatible with index signature.
    Type '{ alias: "colorPicker"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I'm using Angular 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be some problem with versions 15 and 16, it could be due to combability issues with angular or typescript. I was able to replicate the scenario in stackblitz and version 14 still works great, kindly install that and check if it works, below is a stackblitz of the same for reference!

```
npm install ngx-color-picker@14 --save
```

package.json snippet

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.0",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9lhmrt?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,test%2Fpackage.json,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,test%2Fangular.json&title=node.new%20Starter)