# How to use ngx-Color-Picker (version 13) in angular application (Version 15)

Tags: angular, color-picker, angular15

I am not able to implement the ngx-color-picker(v.13) in my Angular (v.15) so can any one tell me

i need to get the color from the color picker. but i am not even able to open the color picker so need correct way of solution with code for this one. if there any please do this as immediately as possible thank you.

Comment: Hi, can you be more specific, "I am not able to implement..." is way too large. Can you provide your code and tell us the errors you get in the DevTools ?

Comment: @RajeshPyla please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77796848/ngx-color-picker-installation-getting-an-error/77797150#77797150)

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the ng-color-picker v14 in Angular 15 => https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-color-picker/releases/tag/v14.0.0

ng-color-picker v13 is not compatible with Angular 15.